# Linux/ Why su command is working from CMD but not from script?

Tags: linux

I have the next script:

```
cd /home
touch $PF ; chown $NU.$NU $PF
su -p -s /bin/sh root -c "node"
```

When I run it, it raises the next error:

```
sh: node: command not found
```

But when I run it from the linux command line, it success and gives me the node command line.

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: different `PATH`? Try `echo $PATH` before executing the command.

Comment: show a `ls -a /path/to/node`

Comment: Question is offtopic here, try http://superuser.com to get an answer.

Comment: @mata `su -p` should preserve environment, including `PATH`, but I'm skeptical as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - yes, but it's not said that he's running it with the same environment in the first place. Maybe it would be useful to know where the differenct between `When I run it...` and `when I run it from the linux command line...` is. @OrSmith - could you please clarify

Comment: @meta I print it and finds that the PATH are diffrents, how I can change the path in the script, that it would run like I run it from the linux command line?

Comment: @mata good catch, it looked like a `PATH` problem. That's why I was skeptical. Glad it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node` is probably not in the `root` user's `$PATH`.

I checked the `su` documentation and noticed the following:

```
-m, -p, --preserve-environment
   Preserve the current environment, except for:

   $PATH
       reset according to the /etc/login.defs options ENV_PATH or ENV_SUPATH (see below);
[...]
   ENV_PATH (string)
       If set, it will be used to define the PATH environment variable when a regular user login. The value can be
       preceded by PATH=, or a colon separated list of paths (for example /bin:/usr/bin). The default value is
       PATH=/bin:/usr/bin.

   ENV_SUPATH (string)
       If set, it will be used to define the PATH environment variable when the superuser login. The value can be
       preceded by PATH=, or a colon separated list of paths (for example /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin). The default
       value is PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin.
```

So while you may have `node` in the *current* `$PATH`, it may not be in `root`'s `$PATH`.

As some commenters have already mentioned, you may try giving an absolute `$PATH`to `node`:

`su -p -s /bin/sh root -c "/path/to/node"`

If you can call `node` from your current user, try `which node` to determine the full path to the executable.

You may also try echoing your `$PATH`.

`su -p -s /bin/sh root -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: Good catch. That is a relative new change to `man su` occurring between coreutil 8.9 and the shuffle to util-linux 2.22.